# Strange characters in webView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using Android WebView element to display text and I can see a strange characters instead of (áéíóú) but only occurs in some devices.

```
String htmlText = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";

String myData = getResources().getString(R.string.text); 

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, myData), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

resources.xml:

```
<resources>

<string name="text">Blá blé blí bló blú.</string> //Here is all text show in image.

</resources>
```

Example:

[image]

I try to use codes like & # 2 3 3 ;(with no spaces) from [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) but the result is the same.